# How to identify the maximum in list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
V = [[10,20,30,40],[30,40,50,-50,-70]]
V_max_result = max(V)
V_max_result_index = V.index(max(V))
print(V_max_result,V_max_result_index)
```

Presently, it is giving output like `[30, 40, 50, -50, -70] 1`

I wanted it to show something like `[[40,3],[50,2]]` where 40 is maximum in first list and it is located at 3.

Comment: Do you mean `list` when you write `string`?

Comment: `{[1,2,3],[4,6],....,[10,20]}`, list? dic?

Comment: Could you please, tell me the code to identify the maximum value and location of maximum value in each string of V (n strings, each string with m values). Store these maximum values and their location in a separate variable V_max (n strings, each string consisting two values, one is maximum and other is location).

Comment: I am beginner to Python (just 3 days). I don't know what is string and list. Could you please help me.

Comment: Please, correct me. I don't know the difference between V = {[1,2,3],[4,6],....,[10,20]} and  V= [[1,2,3],[4,6],....,[10,20]]. Please, enlighten me.

Comment: A `str` (string) is something enclosed by `"..."` or `'...'`. It means basically text. A `list` is an ordered collection of things and denoted by `[thing1, thing2, ...]`. Lists are not hashable (see `set` and `dict`). A `set` is an unordered collection of unique (hashable) things and denoted by `{thing1, thing2, ...}` and finally a `dict` (dictionary) is a collection that maps a unique (hashable) key to a value. It is denoted by `{key1: value1, key2: value2, ...}`. I suggest you read a basic Python tutorial to get a more in depth explanation than that.

Comment: So, now question is clear after you modify, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
V = [[10,20,30,40], [30,40,50,-50,-70]]
print([[max(per_v), per_v.index(max(per_v))] for per_v in V])
```

**Output:**

> [[40, 3], [50, 2]]

Comment: You are just awesome. Excellent. It worked for me. Could you please tell me. How to multiply a I = [1,2,3,4] with each list in V = [[10,20,30,40], [30,40,50,-50]].  I mean I want to get something like V*I = [[10,40,90,160],[30,80,150,-200]]

Comment: You mean `[[10, 40, 90, 160], [30, 80, 150, -200]]`?

Comment: Yes. `[[10, 40, 90, 160], [30, 80, 150, -200]]`

Comment: L = [1, 2, 3, 4]; V = [[10,20,30,40], [30,40,50,-50]]; print([[per_v_v * L[per_v.index(per_v_v)] for per_v_v in per_v] for per_v in V])

Comment: Excellent. It worked. I have worked it on a V(9 lists ,1000 values) and I (1000 values). It just worked and rightly identified the maximum value and index number. If you don't mind. I have one more last question. That is, how to plot V (9 lists, 1000 values) and I (1000 values) on one figure. So, finally, I end up having nine plots in same xy figure. Please, help me.

Comment: Seems about matplotlib, suggest raise another question, I am not skilled about python data visualization

Comment: Sure. I will raise the question. Thanks a lot. You saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

While the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398371/4042267) by [@atline](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6394722/atline) works, it has to iterate three times over each sublist, once to get the maximum, a second time to get the maximum again and then a third time to find its position in the list.

Instead it is easier to find the maximum of tuples, where each tuple is like `(value, index)`. This is almost what `enumerate` returns (`index, value`), just reversed. We can use `zip(values, itertools.count())` for that. It works, because tuples sort by first sorting according to the first entry, then the second.

```
from itertools import count

V = [[10,20,30,40], [30,40,50,-50,-70]]
print([max(zip(per_v, count())) for per_v in V])
# [(40, 3), (50, 2)]
```

If you insist on the inner tuples being lists as well:

```
print([list(max(zip(per_v, count()))) for per_v in V])
# [[40, 3], [50, 2]]
```